# Babel plugin not being applied to node_module

Tags: webpack, babeljs, babel-loader

I need to transform the shorthand for `Math.pow` back into `Math.pow` to run on Safari 10. The code that is calling this shorthand is in a node_module. Simply adding the plugin seemed to not transform the code.

Are plugins not run against node_modules by default?

Below is my `babel.config.js` configuration. I'm running Babel 7 with babel-loader 8 inside Webpack.

```
module.exports = function(api) {
  api.cache(false);

  const presets = [
    [
      "@babel/env",
      {
        modules: "commonjs",
        useBuiltIns: "usage",
      },
    ],
  ];

  const plugins = [["@babel/plugin-transform-exponentiation-operator"]];

  return {
    presets,
    plugins,
  };
};
```

Comment: What is your Webpack config? Also `api.cache(false);` is a bad idea, since it will reduce performance and there's no reason not to cache this.

Comment: I think I'm seeing the problem and it does have to do with my Webpack config. I exclude node_modules from being transpiled.